# "Java is required" although I certainly have Java

Tags: java, google-chrome

When I open pages with Java applets in Chrome (on Ubuntu 12.04), I get a message "Java is required to display some elements in this page". When I click the button "install plug-in", it takes me to the Java download page: http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp

However, I am sure that Java is already installed on my computer, since I develop in Java & Eclipse! Here is it:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Oct 10 18:39 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Oct 10 18:39 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Why do I need to download Java again? Can't I just install the plugin?

Comment: This belongs to http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Might be a difference between 32 bits / 64 bits. When you have a 64 bits Java installed, a 32 bits browser will still report that there is no Java plugin installed. The other way around is also true I think, although I never tried that.

If that is not the case - the browser still needs a Java plugin installed. Having a Runtime on your machine is not enough. If you install Java first and the browser second then you likely already have this issue. Reinstalling Java should fix it, although I'm not too familiar with the Linux version of it to say that for certain.